# Hover Nav Links for HTML5 won't work

Tags: css, html, navigation, nav

So I've read through the topics I could find related to nav bar problems, but none of them have helped me.

I've got a HTML5 nav bar, and I want it to have a color on hover. I thought I'd done the code right, but there's when I hover I got nothing...

HTML:

```
<nav id="mainnav">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="thispage">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
      </header>
```

And the CSS:

```
#mainnav a {
width: 20%;
display: block;
float: left;
background-color: #292929;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
}

#mainnav a:visited, #mainnav a:hover, #mainnav a:active, #mainnav a:focus, #mainnav a.thispage {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #41746D;

}
```

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```css
#mainnav a {
width: 20%;
display: block;
float: left;
background-color: #292929;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
}

#mainnav a:visited, #mainnav a:hover, #mainnav a:active, #mainnav a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #41746D;

}
```

```html
<header>
<nav id="mainnav">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="thispage">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">blog </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
      </header>
```